# Dynamic array gets corrupted in Fortran

Tags: arrays, memory-management, fortran, fortran77

I have to deal with some legacy Fortran code. As far as I prefer to use `ALLOCATE` to deal with arrays, it was a surprise to see things like

```
      INTEGER*4 A(1)
      ... 
      DO 90 J=1,N
      A(J) = SomeValues(J)
90    CONTINUE
```

The problem is silent memory corruption with such arrays. Right after one of them gets filled with values, it becomes corrupted for some unknown reason.

```
      NEQNS=0
      A(1)=1
      DO 100 I=1,NFULL
      IND=A(I)-1
      S=0
      DO 90 J=1,6
      IF(MASK(I,J)) THEN
      S=S+1
      NEQNS=NEQNS+1
      B(NEQNS)=I
      ENDIF
 90   CONTINUE
      A(I+1)=A(I)+S
100   CONTINUE

c Another array starts here to be used in next cycle
      C(1)=1
      DO 700 IL=1,NEQNS
      I=B(IL)  !  Value of B(1) is broken here!
      ....
```

Debugging is not so easy because I have watches like this:
[image]

or like this
[image]

The program was built years ago and it's working, but rebuilt versions are broken. I used x64 and x86 machines, same result.

So, what should I do to fix it, any ideas? Changing allocation method is the least preferred option, as there is too much code to deal with.

Comment: Is the declaration A(1) that of a parameter that has been passed in or the original allocation.  If it is a parameter that has been passed in, you don't need to worry about it.  It is only the original allocation you need to worry about.

Comment: To display 20 elements of CHAD, type CHAD,20 in the watch window.

Comment: @cup I upvoted, tried and updated the post with error. Also these arrays are subroutine parameters, is that a problem?

Comment: Yes it makes a big difference that its a subroutine parameter. The array is allocated (probably statically) in the calling routine. The (1) is old school f77 convention to indicate the subroutine can take an array of unspecified length.  By itself the code posted is ok..

Comment: Sorry, I was in IVF mode.  You can only display 16 bytes at a time in PS4.  Use loc(CHAD),mx where x=a for ascii, b for bytes, w for words, d for doublewords.  To move to the next 16, use loc(CHAD)+16,mx.  I don't know how to get it to display arrays of real numbers if it has been declared as 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is old FORTRAN where memory had to be allocated statically, at compile time.  Frequently programmers just passed the starting address of an array to subroutines, as `array(1)`.  The caller had to have reserved sufficient memory with a declaration.  Your example will only work if this code block came from a procedure for which `A` is a dummy argument.   And the calling routine or higher declared `A` large enough such that `N` and `NFULL+1` are legal elements.